# How do i show an Image (picture) in an Console Programm with C#?

Tags: c#

I want to present the user an Colored Text Based Image of an Picture, but i dont know how to do that, can someone help me out?

I tried it with Console.Backgroundcolor and Console.Forgeground Color but it did only Print the entire Line and not the Background of the CMD or of singe Text letters.

what would i try:
the only Problem i can fix is that i can use like Special fonts like Chinese letters in the Code that it can show correctly but that wont fix the color issue. I would try it like that: Console.backgroundcolor = consolecolor.COLOR* and then console.write("#") and this should show 1 Pixel of the Picture and i would need to repeat this for every singe pixel of the picture. the problem in this is also that the code file would get very fast very Big for the SSD and would cause lag if someone interacts with the file.

Comment: This question seems to essentially be asking the same thing as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204662/how-can-i-present-text-based-pictures-in-color-in-a-console-program-in-c), albeit in a clearer and more direct fashion. It also sounds like you've already made an attempt, but you have not shared this attempt with us (with a textual [mcve] in the question) so we can't help you fix your code.

Comment: You mean like colored ASCII-Art?

Comment: yeah i mean a colored ASCII Art, i only can Color 1 Line of Color but i dont can color 1 singe font in a Line or dont know how to do it, I only tried it with console.backgroundcolor = Consolecolor.COLOR* but idk how to color only a letter in the Line.

Comment: the only Problem i can fix is that i can use like Special fonts like Chinese letters in the Code that it can show correctly but that wont fix the color issue. I would try it like that: Console.backgroundcolor = consolecolor.COLOR* and then console.write("#") and this should show 1 Pixel of the Picture and i would need to repeat this for every singe pixel of the picture. the problem in this is also that the code file would get very fast very Big for the SSD and would cause lag if someone interacts with the file.